# Disply parent page div content into child page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

**Parent.jsp:**

```
<script>function newWindow(){window.open("child.jsp","child",'toolbar = no, status = no beforeShow');
</script>
<form action="child" name="order" id="email" method="post"><BUTTON class=""  type="submit" onclick=newWindow();>ALL Item</BUTTON></form:form> 
<div id="parent_content"><h1>Testing...</h1></div>
```

**Child.jsp:**

```
<script>window.opener.document.getElementById("parent_content").innerHTML;</script>
```

I need to display "parent_content" `div` content in to child page using javascript.

Comment: Would using a `<jsp:include>` be helpful in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this approach.

```
function newWindow(){ window_handler = window.open(...
```

and then after the window has loaded

```
window_handler.document.getElementById(TARGET).innerHTML = 
                          document.getElementById('parent_content').innerHTML;
```